# Suggested edit by OP on a different account

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was going through my Suggested Edits of the day when I came across this :

[image: Review screenshot]

It's pretty obvious that both users are the same person, so editing his own post should be fine.

But, there are still two different users ... Should I approve the edit or reject it ?

Comment: Flag for moderator, looks like they could be abusing the system to get rep, although there is the possibility this could've just been a mistake, I doubt it.

Comment: I would reject it and as George mentioned flag for mod attention

Comment: It could be an honest mistake, logging in from another computer or phone or something and created a second account, but it seems like a good opportunity for a mod flag so that they can decide.

Comment: I would mod flag + approve (the edit itself makes sense and shouldn't be rejected).

Comment: Alright, thanks ! I mod flagged. Is there any way to follow what will happen after this ?

Comment: There is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history). But then you can only know if the mod consider the flag "useful".

Comment: Mods will make a Voight-Kampff test to determine witch one is the original and witch one is the replicant. It's not a 100%, but Mods are still not allowed to ask for a bone marrow sample.

Comment: @Zenoo, OT: how did you get that "black theme", please? Do you use some user script, which one then? Thank you!

Comment: @Victoria I'm using the old [Stack Overflow Dark Colors](https://userstyles.org/styles/97185/stack-overflow-dark-colors) Stylish theme. It's mainly outdated but I've created my own up-to-date version on my computer. I'm not sure if I can share it, though, since its base is not my own work.

Comment: @Zenoo, thanks, hm, doesn't seem to work for me :( Such feature would be great for SE sites, I think.

Comment: @Victoria You need the Stylish browser extension for it to work.

Comment: I see. It's been installed (by "Install with Stylish"), of course. I've even restarted Chrome, but no change at all :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reject the edit as "attempt to reply". It is not obvious at all that it's the same user - it could be someone copying their info, or it could be the same person using multiple accounts to gain reputation, which is not allowed. In either case, a moderator is needed to deal with the issue.

Copy/paste the suggested edit URL, then go to the post that was edited and raise a custom flag for diamond moderator attention. Include the link to the suggested edit.

Official SE policy about multiple accounts here: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: That's what I did, one of the users seems to have been obliterated.

Comment: Multiple accounts of one person are fine as long as they do not earn additional reputation. Getting an accepted edit, however, is a +2 rep operation at that user's current reputation.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Multiple accounts is almost always a sign of something fishy going on, such as voting rings, or more likely the user trying to dodge a ban. Whenever you encounter this, you should always flag a mod, because regular users don't have the tools to tell if something fishy is going on or not.

Comment: Based on what data do you write "almost always"? Are you or have you been a moderator to tell this?

Comment: @ThomasWeller By common sense? What legit reason is there to create multiple accounts?

Comment: Arguably "I can't think of any reason why not" is rarely an argument, but I do believe everyone (don't go "citation needed" me on that, I said *believe*) have been witness to multiple accounts on several occasions, and rarely, if ever, was it warranted. The rarely, is for people that use bots, and create bot accounts.

Comment: Why do I need a legit reason, if it's allowed to have multiple accounts? You want legit reasons? Say I would like one account for answering questions and show my skills in C#. On the other account, I am asking stupid noob questions about Python, because I just started learning Python. I don't want a potential employer to see my noob Python skills.

Comment: Another reason: my employer forces me to have different accounts. So he can see what questions I ask during work time so he knows I'm using SO during work time for work stuff - and not for private hobby stuff. So I have 3 accounts already.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Fair enough. But then how would a regular user even spot that those accounts belong to the same person? The situation like in this post would never arise.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: It may happen by accident - if you logged in with the wrong account. You'll not notice that accidental edit until you see that the edit was not applied. It happened to me once and I got undeserved +2 rep, because the edit was accepted. I lost those 2 rep when I was able to merge the accounts and there was a rep recalc.

Comment: Attempt to reply? What? It'd obviously be 
"conflicts with intent." Most code edits change the meaning of the post somehow.

Comment: @jpmc26 Those are often pretty much the same thing - the editor is either trying to communicate something to the OP or thinks this is wikipedia.

Comment: @Lundin No, "attempt to reply" would be editing a reply of some kind into the post.

Comment: @jpmc26 The edit reasons are quite blunt, we have to deal with them. Often you find edits like a bug correction, which the answer had not at all  considered. But fixing the bug might turn the rest of the answer invalid. In such situations, is it "an attempt to reply" or "conflicts with intent"? It is neither and both. The preferred course of action is to leave a comment and let the OP do the actual fix. The important part is that invalid edits get rejected. Educating the editor about why would be nice, but it is less important than the rejection in itself.